# How would I make a three columned pickerview where a selection in column 1, updates the entries in column 2 and so on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am trying to make a poker pickerview where there is three columns.
In each column I have the standard list of cards, each card representing a row.
If i select 'ace of hearts' in the far left column, then the next column will the standard list excluding the 'ace of hearts'. If i select '3 of clubs' in the 2nd column, then the third column will have the standard list excluding 'ace of hearts' and '3 of clubs'

Can someone tell me how I might do that?

My current code is only for one column with all the three columns representing in one column so not handy to post.

I am using `NSArray` for the default list and am also using a `UIActionSheet`.

```
self.myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43 , 320, 480)];
self.myPickerView.delegate = self;
self.myPickerView.dataSource = self;
[self.myPickerView setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

// Create done button in UIPickerView
self.myPickerViewToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
//  self.myPickerViewToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.myPickerViewToolBar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[self.myPickerViewToolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
self.sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                         delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the picker with 3 columns. You need to create 3 separate arrays to be used for each column.

Then you need to implement the delegate method for handling a row selection. If selected row is for the 1st component then you need to update the 2nd and 3rd arrays to include all cards but the selected on. Then tell the picker to reload the 2nd and 3rd components.

When handling the selected row of the 2nd component you need to update the array for the 3rd component to include all cards but the other two selected cards. Then reload the 3rd component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using UICollectionViewController.

This is as simple as using UITableView.

The following link might be useful to you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12